# c# cannot access class because of protection level

Tags: c#, class, methods

hey guys I'm new to C# and I was practicing classes and methods and that stuff and I did the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Book
    {
        static void Review()
        {
            int x = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Book.Review);
        }
    }
}
```

It's really simple but when i ran it in said that it can't access the "Review" method because of it's protection level, please help

Comment: `public static void Review()...`

Comment: The default accessibility for class members is `private` meaning only the class itself has access to the member, this allows you to hide things like implementation details etc and promotes encapsulation

Comment: Besides making `Review()` public, you also have to call it properly.   `Review()` is void so it does not return anything, so passing it as the parameter of `Console.WriteLine()` would not work.  Your `Main()` method needs to just say: `Book.Review();`

Comment: [Have a quick read of this, it will probably help.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this error is that the default access modifier for methods is `private`, which means that only members of the same class can see them.

Since you want to reference the method from another class in the same namespace, you need to give broader access to the method by changing the access modifier to either `internal` (which means any classes in the same assembly can see it) or `public` (which means it can be seen by everybody).

Either one of these should solve your problem:

```
// Only members of the same assembly can access this method
internal static void Review() { // code omitted }

// Everyone can access this method
public static void Review() { // code omitted }
```

You can read more about access modifiers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).

---

Additionally, you have set the return value of `Review` to `void`, and are then trying to pass this to the `Console.WriteLine()` method, which expects an actual type. This will result in a compile error (something like: "cannot convert `void` to `[someType]`").

In order to solve this you could either just call the method from main and let the method write to the console:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Book.Review();
}
```

Or, my preference would be to have the method return a string, and then write that to the console in the `Main` method (I prefer this because it makes the method more versatile - someone could call it to simply retrieve a review without displaying it to the console, for example):

```
public static string Review()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x.ToString();
}
```

Note that when you call the method, you will need to include the parenthesis after the name:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Book.Review());
}
```

Comment: There is still another issue with the code that would cause it not to compile.  Might want to add that too to give the OP all they need to solve this.

Comment: @maccettura fair enough. I wasn't sure about that since it wasn't part of the question, but I've updated the answer.